# Magento 2: Hide empty rows for custom report

Tags: magento2, backend, reports, custom-reports

I've created a custom report in the Magento 2 backend.

Everything is working great, but by default the results grid shows "We can't find records for this period" for any days where there's no data.

I don't want to physically add a filter form to the report interface, I just want the "show_empty_rows" filter to be set to 0. Is there a way of doing this in the XML layout file, or failing that in one of the supporting classes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317203/removing-empty-rows-in-magento-products-ordered-report

Comment: I did see that, doing it at render time does seem like a bit of a kludge though.

Comment: Also, that's for Magento 1. It doesn't seem to be the same in Magento 2.